# Jagged Button edges in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

How do you remove the jagged edges from a wide button in internet explorer?  For example:

[image]

Comment: I guess drawing them without theming (i.e. set background and border color) is not what you want. It certainly works though.

Comment: Yes, removing the xp theming is a possible solution, but this is a customer application and the rest of the app uses xp themed buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also eliminate Windows XP's styling of buttons (and every other version of Windows) by setting the `background-color` and/or `border-color` on your buttons.

Try the following styles:

```
background-color: black;
color: white;
border-color: red green blue yellow;
```

You can of course make this much more pleasing to the eyes. But you get my point :)

Stack Overflow uses this approach.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you can remove the blank spaces on each end of the button, which has the effect of decreasing the jagged edges. This is accomplished with the following css and a bit of jQuery:

```css
input.button {
   padding: 0 .25em;
   width: 0; /* for IE only */
   overflow: visible;
}

input.button[class] { /* IE ignores [class] */
    width: auto;
}
```

---

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=button]').addClass('button');
});
```

The jQuery is for adding the button class. A more in depth write up can be found [here](http://latrine.dgx.cz/the-stretched-buttons-problem-in-ie).

Comment: If I we're you, I'd test solution on multiple operating systems, in multiple browsers. That is; if you're worried about how your design looks in a non Windows XP environment.

Comment: Also: it seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Should the jQuery selector be `input[type=submit]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the border style of the button with CSS, like this:

```css
/**************************************************************************
 Nav Button format settings
**************************************************************************/
.navButtons
{
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    width: 80;
    height: 20; 
    position: relative; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `overflow: visible;` on the button will cure the issue in IE 6 and 7.

(See http://jehiah.cz/archive/button-width-in-ie)

#### Exceptions

- In IE 6, if `display:block;` is also applied to the button, the above fix won't work.

  Setting the button to `display:inline;` in IE 6 will make the fix work.
- If you have a button like this within a table cell, then the table cell won't contract to the new, smaller width of the button.

  You can fix this in IE 6 by setting `width: 0;` on the button. However, in IE 7 this will make everything but the text of the button disappear.

  (See http://latrine.dgx.cz/the-stretched-buttons-problem-in-ie)

#### More info on styling buttons:

http://natbat.net/2009/Jun/10/styling-buttons-as-links/

Answer (score 1):

Not too much you can do about it, but the good news is that it is fixed in IE8

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-101-buttons-render-stretched-and.html