# submit input doesn't get the :active state in IE8 when I click on the button’s text

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, form-submit

In IE8 if I click exactly on the text-value on a submit button, it doesn't get the properties from the `input:active` CSS selector.

But if I click elsewhere on the button it gets them.

Why? How can I solve it?

Comment: Here’s a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UxuH2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve this by applying `input:focus` to your `input:active` selector declaration:

```
input:active,input:focus{background-color:#000}
```

applying `:active` and `:focus` together are great for ui/ux/etc.... a lot of things.

Comment: True, although if you don’t want your `:active` style applied on focus, then this isn’t desirable. `:active` and `:focus` do have different meanings, after all.

Comment: Thank you very much for this issue! Anyway ie9 is shifting the text value on submit button when clicking and i can't stop it. Any idea?

Comment: i think that bug throws it off -1x-1, try           input:active,input:hover{-ms-background-position:-1px -1px}               whatever the difference is shifting, correct by replacing the right px where -1px is. also, idk if that will target < ie9, i dont think so, but if it does, just put it in conditional comments

Comment: But the text shifts, not the background

Comment: yep - this bug makes me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

That’s really interesting, I’d never noticed that before. IE9 does the same thing: click on the text, and the `:active` styles aren’t applied. Click outside the text, and they are.

IE 6 and 7 had a problem where the edges of buttons would be drawn jaggedly if the button had a lot of text. This can be fixed by [applying `overflow: visible` to the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150535/jagged-button-edges-in-internet-explorer). That doesn’t seem to have any effect on this problem though.

I also tried applying `zoom: 1` to give the button layout (although I think form controls already have layout), but that had no effect either.

Unfortunately, it looks like there isn’t a CSS workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`:active` selector <sub>edit</sub> **in IE** <sub>/edit</sub> is used to select and style the active link (anchor) element, not input.

Use Javascript to attach on focus event to your button.

Comment: `:active` seems to work fine for selecting the active state of `<input type="submit">` in other browsers. The CSS 2.1 spec [says “in CSS1, the ':active' pseudo-class only applied to links”](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) — so presumably in CSS 2.1, it applies to inputs as well.

Comment: You’re entirely right that JavaScript is the way around the issue though.

Comment: @Paul you are right, but I've mentioned it for IE, I've edited the answer

Comment: that’s not entirely true re IE though — `:active` does have an effect, but only when the user clicks outside of the button’s text.

Answer (score 0):

Great, thanks Albert for mentioning the `:focus` selector. I was looking for a solution to the 'clickthrough' problem for a couple of hours now, without finding good information.

My problem was a similar one to OP but for a link instead of input button.

Basically, I have a multiline link/button and in IE it was not possible to only use the `:active` selector on the link to change the button's properties since the `span` inside the `a` would not 'shine' through.

Now, I use `a:active` and `a:focus` on the `a` together with `onclick="this.blur();"` and it works like a charm for my purposes.

Please have a look at my solution on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pezzi/UzARF/