# ie8 input[type=submit] with background image - text not clickable

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a standard button (input[type=submit) with a problem in IE8.

Because, IE 8 doesn't do filters very well, I resorted to a repeating background image. This works fine in default and hover states, but the background image does not change if I click on the button text, invoking :active state.

Note: It works if I click elsewhere on the button but not on the text. I've tried removing the image in :active state but the button still doesn not change from the hover image.

Has anyone come across this and/or found a solution?

To make it worse jsfiddle doesn't seem to support IE8 anymore, so can't even put together an example.

Comment: Frankly speaking I hardly understand what is wrong. Try jsfiddle again. They have some problems from time to time. I do not believe they does not support IE. Additionally, you can use http://jsbin.com/ as an alternative.

Comment: You have similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886888/submit-input-doesnt-get-the-active-state-in-ie8-when-i-click-on-the-buttons-t . Try adding :focus and :active together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try workaround with `:focus`

Maybe some like this, I don't have your code but you can try this:

```
input:active,input:focus
{
   background-image: ...
}
```

You have similar problem here: [submit input doesn't get the :active state in IE8 when I click on the button’s text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886888/submit-input-doesnt-get-the-active-state-in-ie8-when-i-click-on-the-buttons-t)